# ZK Message Box Confirmation

Tags: java, zk

I'm using ZK and found some strange behavior. The code:

```
@Listen("onClick = button#load")
public void load() {
    int result = Messagebox.show("Are you sure to execute Load?", "Execute?",
            Messagebox.YES | Messagebox.NO, Messagebox.QUESTION);
    log.debug("Result: {}", result);
    if (result == Messagebox.YES) {
        (new Thread(new Job("Load"))).start();
        message.setValue("Job " + "Load " + " is Executed at " + new Date());

        log.info("Load Called");
    } else {
        log.debug("Load Not Called");
    }
}
```

Either **Yes** or **No** is Clicked, it return 1 as int. Logs:

```
 02-Oct-2016 23:59:31.725 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.Controller.load Result: 1
 02-Oct-2016 23:59:31.726 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.Controller.load Load Not Called
 02-Oct-2016 23:59:39.541 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] com.Controller.load Result: 1
 02-Oct-2016 23:59:39.542 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] com.Controller.load Load Not Called
```

**How to make it right?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of ZK are you using?

The javadoc says :

> @return the button being pressed (one of {@link #OK}, {@link #CANCEL},
>   {@link #YES}, {@link #NO}, {@link #ABORT}, {@link #RETRY},  and {@link  #IGNORE}).
>
> Note: if the event processing thread is disabled, it always returns
>   {@link #OK}.

But if you check the [documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/UI_Patterns/Event_Threads) about the event processing thread, it says :

> [Since ZK 7.0.0 deprecated to enable the event thread according to Java Servlet Specification that may prohibit the creation of new threads]

So should notify ZK to update its javadoc as if you are using ZK7 or 8 the method will always return 1 right away.

To answer your question, if you want to call specific action depending on which button is clicked:

```
@Listen("onClick = button#load")
public void load() {
    Messagebox.show("Are you sure to execute Load?", "Execute?", Messagebox.YES | Messagebox.NO, 
        Messagebox.QUESTION, new EventListener<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(final Event evt) throws InterruptedException {
                if (Messagebox.ON_YES.equals(evt.getName())) {
                    // Code if yes clicked
                } else {
                    // Code if no clicked
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've modified to use event listener. Maybe I read an older document.